# How to add legend to Mosaic Dataset (ArcGIS Image Service Layer)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, legend, mosaic-dataset

I have snow cover data of MODIS (46 images for an year) I put them in a mosaic dataset (with in a file geodatabase) and published them as an Image Service from ArcCatalog and added a time slider.

I am using the ArcGIS Javascript api to make a little web app. Now the last step I'm stuck at is making a legend. (plus I'm a beginner at javascript!)

I read over here ( https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/legend-amd.html) that the legend class supports some specific layer types. I believe the work I have done above is not supported by it? Because I have tried the normal legend making functions but to no use. Can anybody guide me how to make the legend?